# How to use CASE for non-boolean results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Question how to create this in SQL Server

```
IF ADJ_DAYS_OFF_FLAG= '1' and   ADJ_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS ='1'
THEN [value] of ADJ_DAYS_OFF 
ELSE [value] of ELIG_DAYS_OFF
```

I have:

| PARTICIPANT | VALUE | NAME | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JAMES | 0 | ADJ_DAYS_OFF_FLAG | 2022-12-1 |
| JAMES | 0 | ADJ_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS | 2022-12-1 |
| JAMES | 0 | ADJ_DAYS_OFF | 2022-12-1 |
| JAMES | 8 | ELIG_DAYS_OFF | 2022-12-1 |

I want:

| PARTICIPANT | VALUE | PERIOD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JAMES | 64% | 2022-12-1 |

I've tried:

```
SELECT [PARTICIPANT], 
FORMAT((CASE 
WHEN [PERIOD]='2021-12-01' THEN ((22-SUM([VALUE]))/22)/100
WHEN [PERIOD]='2022-01-01' THEN ((23-SUM([VALUE]))/23)/100
WHEN [PERIOD]='2022-02-01' THEN ((21-SUM([VALUE]))/21)/100
END), 'P') AS 'PERCENT', [PERIOD]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE CASE
WHEN [NAME]='ADJ_DAYS_OFF_FLAG' AND [NAME]='ADJ_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS' AND SUM([VALUE])>='2'
THEN [NAME]='ADJ_DAYS_OFF'
ELSE [NAME]='ELIG_DAYS_OFF'
END
GROUP BY [PARTICIPANT], [PERIOD]
;
```

Comment: I may add [business days] as a Case too

Comment: bring clarity to your question

Comment: @RF1991 Does the question make more sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Simple conditional aggregation seems to suffice

```sql
SELECT
  t.PARTICIPANT,
  t.PERIOD,
  CONCAT(
    (23 - CASE WHEN
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'ADJ_DAYS_OFF_FLAG'    THEN t.VALUE END) *
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'ADJ_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS' THEN t.VALUE END)
     > 0 THEN
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'ADJ_DAYS_OFF'         THEN t.VALUE END)
     ELSE
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.NAME = 'ELIG_DAYS_OFF'        THEN t.VALUE END)
     END
     ) * 100 / 23
    ,'%')
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.PARTICIPANT,
  t.PERIOD;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f13b01cfe954b53d3d05c64f4d88b11)

Comment: this does not answer my question. My question is based on I am to select a value per participant per period base on IF ADJ_DAYS_OFF_FLAG= '1' and ADJ_CONSECUTIVE_DAYS ='1' then [value] of ADJ_DAYS_OFF ELSE [value] of ELIG_DAYS_OFF. Your code doesnt address the if.

Comment: Then you can just add `PERIOD` into the grouping https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f13b01cfe954b53d3d05c64f4d88b11

Comment: The value I divide by changes each period, how would I denote that with your code?

Comment: Not sure, you would probably need a calendar table that tells you that. Or you can possibly calculate it, but I don't know what your rules are

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the `IIF` keyword for this. (Short for `Inline IF`)

Here is a [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp).

Here is an example:

```
SELECT Username,
  IIF(Role = 'Manager' OR Role = 'Lead', 1, 0) AS IsSupervisor
FROM Users
```

Comment: I wrote ``` iif(([name]='adj_days_off_flag' and [name]='consecutive_days' and (sum([value]>='2'), [name]='adj_days_off', [name]='days_off') ``` but ger incorrect syntax near '='